# Django Heroku Deployment No Module Found

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a django project at
https://testing-mike.herokuapp.com/
The deployment succeeded but it throws a no module found error. The same module with wsgi works on the local shell using this command : gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 solvesto.wsgi:application
but fails on heroku.

Following are the logs:

File "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-12-25T16:39:06.879705+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'solvesto'
2020-12-25T16:39:06.879826+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-25 16:39:06 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-12-25T16:39:06.909498+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-25 16:39:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-12-25T16:39:06.909592+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-12-25 16:39:06 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

Comment: It is possible that solvesto is installed locally, but not in heroku. Is solvesto included in requirements.txt? You could also access the heroku's terminal and check if the module is present and if you can import it

Comment: @EduardoMatsuoka Solvesto isnt a dependency,so its not in requirements. Its the name of my module, my wsgi file shows solvesto.py.

Comment: I see, so it can be many things. Is your Procfile pointing to the right wsgi file? Check for any mistyping. Also, I think it it's a good idea to go through a checklist so you didn't missed something. Mozilla has an excellent tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Deployment